# Making a smart notification list

Tags: php, notifications

**Scenario**

A image website that has basic features such as upload, comment, like, follow users etc.

Now i have a basic notification system that i built very quickly which just basically when a event happens such as an upload or like it is inserted into the `notifications` table, and then has a `read` column which determines whether the user has seen it or not, simple.

The current example output would be something like this,

```
John Doe liked Picture of my cat.
Sarah Doe liked Picture of my cat.
Adam Doe liked Picture of my cat.
Sarah Doe liked Picture of my cat.
Henry Doe is now following you.
```

Which just basically is ordered by time of input.

Now what i would like to achieve is something similar to the following,

```
4 users liked Picture of my cat.
Henry Doe is now following you.
```

I am trying hard to wrap my average PHP knowledge around this and the best way i can think of is doing something like this.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notifications` WHERE `read` = '0' LIMIT 20");
$likes = array();
$following = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    if($row['type'] == "like"){

        array_push($likes,$row['id']);

    }   elseif($row['type'] == "following"){

        array_push($following,$row['id']);

    }

}
```

And then somehow sorting them to display correctly. But it still seems very complicated.

Also one more thing to think about if anyone comes up with a suggestion, would it be a good idea to have a algorithm in place that would group them even if they are not directly after each other, for example 5 minutes apart but with different notifications in between, for example

```
John Doe liked Picture of my cat.
John Doe is now following you.
Sarah Doe liked Picture of my cat.
Sarah is now following you.
```

Into

```
2 People liked Picture of my cat.
2 New Users are now following you.
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Okay thank you. Any ideas towards my question?

Comment: This is just a friendly comment. If you want to make a facebook like site, you need a good database knowledge as well as php knowledge. If this is a small project targeting limited amount of users, no problem, you'll learn what you need by asking here. But if your project is meant to be bigger, you should learn much more about SQL.

Comment: It isn't going to be a facebook like site at all. The only similarity is that users can upload photos. But thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe the best solution is using `GROUP BY` in `SQL` not at `PHP` side. You need to group the results by the event type. If there is a single result, just show the single result by using a second query. If there are more than one results, just show `COUNT(*)` as you intended.

EDIT: Examples.

```
SELECT event_type, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `notifications` WHERE `read` = '0' GROUP BY event_type

result:
event_type  count
----------  -----
4           4
6           2
9           1
12          2
```

Then you may run second queries for the events which are only appeared once.

```
SELECT * FROM `notifications` WHERE `read` = '0' AND `event_type` = '9'
```

of course you should also change their read status at the end

```
UPDATE `notifications` SET `read` = '1' WHERE `read` = '0'
```

These are just fast prepared examples. You should take care of special cases, updating only shown entries etc.

I used `event_type` as a field. I believe you have a field like this. You should rename that part according to your database structure.

Comment: was just writing this answer aswell, GROUP BY is the solution to your problem +1

Comment: But how would i determine what time frame to group by, by?

Comment: you update the "read" flag in the notification entries :-) Edit: anyway, you would have to determine if at least one entry is not already read by the user and then use all of them.

Comment: You may use MIN() MAX() for date functions. If you want to group by for different time frames, you can group by special date cases in the GROUP BY part with additional parameters or discard the unwanted dates at the WHERE part of the sql.

Comment: I don't exactly understand i am afraid, would you mind writing a example piece of code?

Comment: Sorry, i've forgot the GROUP BY part in the first example sql. Updated again.

Comment: I will try and make something from your advice, will let you know soon!

Comment: Quick question, to grab all of the notifications that apply to your account, should i make it so that in the table it should have the users ID or should i have a query that looks for your id when type is "following" and then for likes load a array of all your uploads then search for which have been liked?

Comment: your table should have both fields and your query should have both in WHERE part of the sql like "WHERE event_type = 6 AND user_id = 3".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15669/discussion-between-user1527354-and-emir-akaydin)

Answer (score 0):

Taking an example from FB, the notifications are processed regardless of count. If we click on the number of likes on FB we get a kick back of who liked it, so the count is just a place holder for processed items.

When you are processing keep a count of notifications

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notifications` WHERE `read` = '0' AND 'date_added' > {SOMETIMEEXPRESSION} GROUP BY type LIMIT 20");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
if ($curType != $row['type']) {
    $curType = $row['type'];
    $curCount = 0;
    //Other Type switch conditions
 }
//    do the magic that you wish to do for the type.
}
```

Comment: But how would this work with multiple images that have been liked, for example the notifications that have been unread are 4 likes on one image, 2 on another, one on another and 3 people following?

Comment: You can do addition GROUP BY clauses.